# Probability of a full house with multiple people playing

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I am trying to calculate the probability of a full house if 3 friends are playing Texas Hold'em. At the starting round each player is dealt 2 cards, and at each continuing round each player is dealt an additional card. Each player can be dealt no more than 5 cards in total.

If I have a pair at the initial round, what would be the probability that I get a Full House?

My approach so far has been

[$\binom{13}{1}$$\binom{4}{2}$$\binom{12}{1}$$\binom{4}{3}$ + $\binom{13}{1}$$\binom{4}{2}$$\binom{2}{1}$$\binom{12}{1}$$\binom{4}{2}$]/
$\binom{52}{5}$

The first part is if I have the case **`xxyyy`** and the second is for the case **`xxxyy`**

Does this look good or am I missing something?

Comment: Since you have a pair, there are only $50$ unknown cards, and you will be dealt $3$ more cards, so the denominator should be $\binom{50}{3}$  I don't understand how you got the numerator at all.  I would say it's $12\binom43+2\cdot12\binom42$

Comment: I believe we need to consider the case where the other suits of your pair card being held by other players?

Comment: @nyeowNyeow As I understand the rules, the first two cards are dealt face down, so you have no information as to the holdings of the other players.  They're just part of the unknown $50$ remaining cards.  I've never played the game, so perhaps I'm in error.

Comment: @saulspatz Oh I see. Thanks! I believe Will's answer divided by $P$(getting pair in first two cards) equals yours